# Cannot uninstall Foxit Reader plugin for Firefox

Tags: browser-addons, plugins, uninstall, firefox, foxit-reader

I recently installed Foxit Reader plugin for Firefox, but I like to uninstall it now. When I open the addons window, there is only one option under this plugin: *Disable*. I just want to uninstall, not to disable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have to do it manually. From the [Mozilla KB](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Troubleshooting+plugins?bl=n&s=remove%20plugins&as=q#Manually_uninstalling_a_plugin):

Manually uninstalling a plugin

If you can't use an uninstaller program to remove a plugin, you can remove it manually:

1. In the Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.
2. Search for the preference: `plugin.expose_full_path`.
3. Double-click on the `plugin.expose_full_path` preference in the list to change the value to `true`.
4. Enter **about:plugins** into the Location bar to display the *About Plugins* page.
5. Each entry in the *About Plugins* page will have "File name:" followed by a path. Use Windows Explorer to navigate to the folder shown for the plugin you want to remove.
6. Rename the file to something other than its normal name - e.g. `npswf32` becomes `Xnpswf32`.

The plugin will be removed.

Comment: This information is outdated (Dec 2014). For any firefox >V.22: expose_full_path is gone. **Instead**: enter `about:plugins` (instead of `about:config`) and there you get the paths. Navigating to each path, renaming from npWhatsover.dll to DISABLED_npWhatsoever.dll is my recommendation (for me was even possible while FF open), restart firefox and the cruft is gone (verify in `about:plugins` or the more visual end-user `about:addons`).